# save response in nsmutabledictionary ? swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

My code for getting response in Alamofire 4.0

```
Alamofire.request(webpath).responseJSON
    {
        response in

        //here I want to store response in nsmutabledictionary
    }
```

And within  that response I have Data object , which contains data like below

```
{"Success":"True","Data":[{"Id":"4","Name":"xyz"}]
```

I want to save that Data object in `NSMutableArray` for displaying in `UITableview`

Comment: As always do not use `NSMutable...` in Swift unless you have absolutely no choice. Here you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get result `Dictionary` from `Alamofire` response like this.

```
Alamofire.request(webpath).responseJSON
{
    response in

    switch(response.result) {
    case .success(_):
        if let dic = response.result.value as? [String: Any], 
           let array = dic["Data"] as? [[String: Any]] {
            print(array)
        }
    case .failure(_):
        print(response.result.error)
    }
}
```

**Note:** Use Swift native `Dictionary` and `Array` instead of `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`.